# test_user cannot be added because it does not have a primary key

Tags: postgresql, netbeans-8

I can't connect my POSTGRESQL database table to my new netbeans8 web service. The alert message is: *test_user cannot be added because it does not have a primary key.

[image: 'See the message here]

But my table is having a primary id. Here is the SQL colde:

```
 -- Table: public.test_user

-- DROP TABLE public.test_user;

CREATE TABLE public.test_user
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    index_user character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    name character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    username character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    phone character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    email character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    password character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    image character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    date date,
    CONSTRAINT user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.test_user
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Comment: Why are you using such an outdated NetBeans version? I wouldn't be surprised if that can't properly handle the identity column. Also what is the version of the Postgres JDBC driver you are using?

Comment: NetBeans 12.5 with driver version 42.2.16 works just fine with your table definition.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild your table and put the PRIMARY KEY constraint in-line:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test_user
(
    id integer
      CONSTRAINT user_pkey PRIMARY KEY
      NOT NULL
      GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    index_user character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    name character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    username character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    phone character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    email character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    password character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    image character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    date date
) TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

This may allow your older version of NetBeans to "see" the constraint.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=da7e62a573851b261ea5d55230eaa256)

Comment: Does the syntax make any difference in the result? [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c2e891239f21d29539895c585d1b1ed6)

Comment: It shouldn't, but who knows what NetBeans 8 is looking for?